# Chrome's Data-Saver feature enabled in Crosswalk WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, crosswalk-runtime

In Chrome version 45.0.2454.85 the Developer Tools show a yellow warning at the top of the window with the text: "Consider disabling [Chrome Data Saver](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?hl=en) when debugging" whenever I connect to my Cordova/Crosswalk app on my phone.

Is Data Saver enabled in the Crosswalk plugin (version 1.2, WebView version 44.0.2403.117)? If so, can I turn it off?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: If I did, I’ve since forgotten :-/